# Count records from DatasourceB based value from DatasourceA

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm new to PowerApps - I'm attempting to count and display the number of visits made by the manager to each of his/her stores.
I've created a screen that displays a filtered list of stores assigned to the user (manager). I want to display a value of the total visits the user has made to each store. and the date of his/her last visit.  Both datasources are Sharepoint list. with all info about each visit held in a list called Store_Visit. I tried the following code but I get an error stating the '=' is an invalid argument type. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
CountIf(
    Store_Visit.Store_SCID,
    (Store_Visit.Store_Name = ThisItem.STORE_NAME) &&
        (Store_Visit.ChannelManagerName = vCurrentUser.FullName))
```

I expect to see 
Storename1
Total visits = 5

Storename2
Total visits = 3

StoreName3
Total visits = 2

etc

Comment: Can you show the formula you're using please? It looks like it didn't get added correctly

Comment: ``` CountIf(Store_Visit.Store_SCID,(Store_Visit.Store_Name = ThisItem.STORE_NAME) && 
(Store_Visit.ChannelManagerName = vCurrentUser.FullName) 
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are trying to compare two items with different data types. You can do a sanity check by creating labels for `Store_Visit.Store_Name` and `ThisItem.STORE_NAME` and make sure they give you what you expect. You might have to add `.Value` to the end of `Store_Visit.Store_Name` to turn it into text. [Here is an example](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/countif-on-a-choice-field/td-p/25404)